# SmsManager does not send sms

Tags: android, eclipse

I tried to send an SMS using SMS Manager. I have sufficient permissions. And I went through some answers given in Stackoverflow. This is my code. It works on my phone but doesnt send the SMS. 'SMS Sent is shown' Help me. Thank in advance

```
package com.example.esms;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final EditText textName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText textPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Button buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(textPhone.toString(), null, textName.toString(), null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
    });


}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `textPhone.toString()` to `textPhone.getText().toString()`, and `textName.toString()` to `textName.getText().toString()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and it worked. Sorry if I bothered you  for such a small issue. Im an infant to android and java.